# Is it possible to render new pages on first view in NextJS during runtime?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Currently I'm using `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` to prerender the latest X number of articles before my site goes live. This works great, but if a new article is created and shown on the front page while the site is still running, the new article returns a 404 page.

What I'd like is if a page doesn't exist, the id (like mysite.com/posts/id in the `/posts/[id].js` file) is passed to a function so that the page can be prerendered on the server during runtime. I don't want to default to `getServerSideProps`, since that would render the page on every request, what I'm looking for is to permanently render the page, and save it as a crawlable file just like `getStaticProps` does, only during runtime.

TL:DR I'm looking for a `getStaticPaths`/`getStaticProps` behavior during runtime. Is this possible in NextJS?

If not, how could I have new articles readily available without having to take down the server, build it again, and start it up again every so often, which seems horribly unmanageable.

Answer (score 5):

> TL:DR I'm looking for a getStaticPaths/getStaticProps behavior during runtime. Is this possible in NextJS?

Yes and no. There's a [revalidate option](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) which, as of now, requires a client-side request to invalidate stale data. Then another client-side request must be made to retrieve the updated data. This has the unavoidable consequence of User A seeing stale data (triggering the revalidation) and User B seeing the up-to-date data. As of yet, there's no way to programmatically trigger a revalidation upon a CRUD (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE) event.

A (not recommended) workaround is to manually trigger a client-side request immediately after a CRUD event. This way, in theory, User A and User B should always see up-to-date data. Unfortunately, this means longer response times for CRUD operations.

In short, right now `getServerSideProps` is the **only available option to guarantee 100% up-to-date data for SEO indexing**. Otherwise, if you don't care for SEO indexing, then **client-side requests should suffice.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would use getServerSideProps, but it doesn't seem you can use it together with getStaticProps, also it will cause pages to load slow for everyone since all data api calls need to be made for each request. I did find where the prerendered files are located, and it seems like I could create a script that generates a new html and json file manually when a new page is created, via a message queue trigger. I'm just shocked that there's no built-in method of doing this in NextJS... How do large sites handle new content? I can't imagine shutting down and building every time

Comment: Is there any way to catch a 404 error to manually handle it? At least if a user tries to open a page with a new article ID, I can maybe catch it, manually render the page and return it?

Comment: You can catch potential 404 pages by looking into the [fallback option](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true) which is supposed to render a predefined page, then swap it out with new data. I don't have much personal usage with it, so I can't comment on its performance.

Comment: There's been some talk about validation through an API event trigger, but nothing has come of it yet (other than a possible future implementation in v10).

Answer (score 3):

It seems the answer was simpler than I thought. Within getStaticPaths, you just need to set fallback: true, then within the function component add some fallback content that viewer will see temporarily while the server renders the new page and sends it back. Example [id].js:

```
export default function Post({ postProps}) {
    const router = useRouter()
    
    if (router.isFallback) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

This will allow the server to use `getStaticProps` on the new ID and render the new page, while the client sees `Loading...` then once rendering is complete, the client is given the new page. This render only needs to happen once for new pages and will be readily available for any subsequent views or SEO crawlers.

[reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fallback-true)